# Removing unwanted text from array or fpdf

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, fpdf

I have a sql query which pulls the presenter fields from the table.  The presenter fields are in an array.  So I do this:

```
//convert presenter data from array to string   
    $cleanpresenters = parse_ini_string($data['presenters'],TRUE);
    foreach ($cleanpresenters as $name=>$val1) 
    {
            $name = trim($name);
            $presenters[] = $name;
            $convertedPresenters .= "$name, {$val1['department']}, {$val1['institution']}\n";
    };
```

which converts this:

Array
(
    [Doe, John undefined] => Array
        (
            [middle_name] => 
            [department] => Leadership Studies
            [institution] => Any State University
            [city] => Dayton
            [state] => Oh
            [country] => United States
            [office_phone] => 123-456-11258
            [cell_phone] => 
            [email_address] => John.doe@anywhere.edu
            [website] => 
        )

```
[Doe, Jane undefined] => Array
    (
        [middle_name] => 
        [department] => Leadership Studies
        [institution] => Any State University
        [city] => Dayton
        [state] => Oh
        [country] => United States
        [office_phone] => 123-45-7896
        [cell_phone] => 
        [email_address] => John.doe@anywhere.edu
        [website] => 
    )
```

)

to this:

Doe, John undefined, Leadership Studies, Any State University

Doe, Jane undefined, Leadership Studies, Any State University

in both the output echo and the pdf created using fpdf.  My question is - how do I eliminate (replace with space) the "undefined" from all the strings?  I have tried using preg_replace, but I am enough of a newb that I can't get it to work correctly.  Am I on the right track or completely off base? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to replace a string in php, try use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$new_string =  str_replace("undefined"," ","Doe, John undefined, Leadership Studies, Any State University");
```

Comment: Will that work if the names will be different each time?  The only thing that will remain constant is the format of the arrays converted to the string and the word undefined instead of a middle name.  All the other information - first name, last name, institution, etc. will be different.

Comment: stre_replace  replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string. So it work if the replacement text is always the same, in this case "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it with `preg_replace`:

```
$cleanpresenters = parse_ini_string($data['presenters'],TRUE);
foreach ($cleanpresenters as $name=>$val1) 
{
        $name = trim(preg_replace('/ undefined/i', '', $name));
        $presenters[] = $name;
        $convertedPresenters .= "$name, {$val1['department']}, {$val1['institution']}\n";
};
```

There is a space before the `undefined`, but you can take it out if it won't always be there.